# Maven project initializer

Tags: maven, maven-3

Is there an easy way to initialize maven projects which is equal to spring initializer? (https://start.spring.io/).
What I meant was an easy interface rather than going through command line or without using paid IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Or from the command line, using the spring-boot-sample-simple-archetype

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.springframework.boot -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-boot-sample-simple-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE
```

For basic maven projects I have a shell script in my work directory, using the maven quick start archetype:

```
$ cat quickArch.sh
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid command line. And this is not for spring boot projects. Anyone will use spring starter site for that. Anyway thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: @Akalanka sorry didn't read the question, I've updated answer for completeness, think other answer is better for this question.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse, you can create a new Maven Project in "File -> New -> Project". Then you can choose a Maven archetype (which is essentially a project template) and enter the parameters.